# How to Create "Factory Reset" Image on Partitioned Drive

Tags: windows, system-restore, factory-defaults

I'm building a computer.  How do I create a "factory reset" (recovery/re-install) image on a partitioned drive?  Is it just a matter of copying the Windows install DVD to the drive?

Comment: If you want a custom Windows 7 recovery partition similar to what OEM's use see this article....http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/21978-Windows-7-OEM-Recovery-Partition-tools-creator-Free

Comment: I would post this as an answer but there is no good way to reproduce the article here on Super User, posting an answer and only linking to another site is frowned upon here at SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install the OS and get everything setup the way you like you can either use the built in tools for Windows 7 to create an image or you can use an off the shelf type product like Acronis to create a full image of the drive, partitions and all.

Comment: I think what the OP is looking for (or maybe I should ask this separately) is how to create an alternate booting partition specifically for reloading the OS (with pre-install environment and all), like the ones that many OEMs pre-load on their systems.

Comment: Windows already has that built in System Restore in Accessories >> System Tools >> System Restore. Windows can also create a complete system image which allows you to save the image as a DVD, on a network location, or on another drive. Go to Control Panel >> System & Security >> Backup and restore. If you want to store the image on another drive then the second option would be best

Comment: System Restore is not quite the same as "Factory Reset".  Regarding the Backup Image, can you restore the image just by booting from that DVD?

Comment: Yes you can, you would just boot the dead machine up using a Windows DVD then instead of selecting the install option you can go to Advanced and then select Restore from Image.

Comment: There are other products out the too like Acronis that will create full system images which you can store on DVD or any location and if something were to happen just boot the system with your Acronis CD and then load the image.

Comment: http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/

Comment: For what your trying to do I wouldnt do the System Restore, instead create a full system image using the tools Windows has. Control Panel >> System & Security >> Backup and restore >> Create System Image

Comment: See, what I'd like to do (again, not sure if this should be a separate question, or if it is the OP's intent) is boot from a secondary partition that contains *everything* you need to do the restore - boot environment, restore tools, and image.  Booting from separate disks that could easily get lost or damaged is not quite so convenient to me, let alone Joe End User.

Comment: All the packages i've seen out there would require you to at minimum insert a boot cd, as is the case with Acronis or Ghost. You can store the system image on another drive but in either event you would need to insert a boot disk to kick off the process.

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe it will help:   http://www.tech-forums.net/computer_articles/restore/restore-disk.php

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx: How much space do you think I should allocate for a recovery partition?  If I just want the basic Windows installation, you think 12GB or 20GB would be sufficient?

Comment: If it is a fresh install I would say the entire OS would be less then 10gb, but I would probably set aside 15 - 20 GB if you had the extra room.